# Eloquent with não faz inner join?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Lembro de antigamente "descobrir" que em uma query utilizando o Eloquent, se eu usasse o `with` o Laravel fazia um `inner join`.

Hoje por acaso fui verificar as queries de um projeto e...

```
[2014-11-20 23:21:16] sql.INFO: select * from `ocurrences` where `ocurrences`.`deleted_at` is null order by RAND() limit 4 {"bindings":[],"time":3.58,"name":"mysql"} []
[2014-11-20 23:21:16] sql.INFO: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` in ('7') {"bindings":["7"],"time":0.49,"name":"mysql"} []
[2014-11-20 23:21:16] sql.INFO: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = '7' limit 1 {"bindings":["7"],"time":0.51,"name":"mysql"} []
[2014-11-20 23:21:16] sql.INFO: select * from `tags` limit 5 {"bindings":[],"time":0.41,"name":"mysql"} []
```

Neste caso, estou fazendo a query desta forma:

```
/**
 * Get random ocurrences for home
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function randomForHome()
{
  return static::with('user')
    ->orderByRaw('RAND()')
    ->limit(4)
    ->get();
}
```

O que está errado e/ou como eu faço **com o Eloquent** joins?

Answer (score 4):

Eu precisei usar o método `join()` do Eloquent. Inicialmente eu achava que o `with` realizava joins também, mas pelo jeito não mais.

Sendo assim tive que trocar o `with` por: `join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'ocurrences.user_id')`.

Enfim, é isso.

Segue a solução final abaixo:

```
/**
 * Get random ocurrences for home
 * @return Eloquent
 */
public static function randomForHome()
{
  return static::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'ocurrences.user_id')
    ->orderByRaw('RAND()')
    ->limit(4)
    ->get();
}
```

Comment: with simplesmente inclui o método registrado para relacionamento no seu model. No caso, um select pra cada tabela.

Answer (score 1):

Também pode ser feito assim.

```
DB::table('TABELA')
->join('TABELA2', 'TABELA1.ID', '=', 'TABELA2.ID')
->where('1 = 1')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Todo mundo tem esta dúvida referente o "porque não usar join" do eloquent, bom, eu também não sou muito por dentro não... mas realmente acredito que seja por alguma questão de performance ou ambiguidade.

Ao usar o with ele irá executar a query do pai e executar uma segunda query para recuperar todos os filhos de relacionamentos, mantendo acho que a integridade.

```
$pedidos = $pedidos
    ->select('id', 'id_pedido', 'hora_pedido', 'local_venda', 'cidade', 'estado')
    ->with(['itens' => function($q){
            $q->where('clientes_id', \Session::get('idClienteTray'));
            $q->select('PedidosTray_id', 'id_produto', 'quantidade');

        },
        'itens.produto' => function($q)
        {
            $q->where('clientes_id', \Session::get('idClienteTray'));
            $q->select('id_produto', 'descricao');

        }])
```

Este é o conhecido método **Eager loading**

Aqui tem um amigo que da uma possível explicação: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920540/why-cant-laravel-eloquent-use-join-for-eager-loading